# How to open a readable file and jump to specific line in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have created a link using QLabel in PyQt5. Now I want, when i click on that link, it should open the file and automatically cursor goes to line number 5. What will be the approach or code to achieve this using PyQt5 or atleast in Python3.

Comment: What kind of file? And are you displaying the file inside the GUI?

Comment: It will be plain text file. Display in GUI will be an editor, can be notepad.

Answer (score 1):

You could display the text in a QPlainTextEdit and use QTextCursor to move to the 5th line.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        with open ('file.txt') as file:
           text = file.read()
        editor = QPlainTextEdit()
        editor.setPlainText(text)
        cursor = editor.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextBlock, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor, 4)
        editor.setTextCursor(cursor)
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(editor)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Template()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```